# Ionic5 IOSFilePicker convert uri to blob

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic5, filepicker

I use this method:

```
getFiles(){
 this.filePicker.pickFile().then(uri => {
console.log('uri '+uri);
})
.catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
}
```

And I want convert uri to blob because I need to upload it.
I tried several methods that I found on the forums but none of them work.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you have the path on the device (uri) you can use

```
cordova-plugin-file
```

to fetch the file and read its contents

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

Comment: I try with cordova-plugin-file but blob is empty. I think I've tried everything I could find on Google but nothing works. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: what does the URI look like which filepicker returns?

Comment: the uri look like this " /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4A24AADB-A243-49C8-821E-192A4EA901FF/tmp/com.focus-Inbox/presentation(3)___86f3ab54-9161-4452-965a-116dddc8eb7d.pdf". I try to add this also "file:///" before uri.

Comment: Try navigating to the file on your device and check if it truly exists. Also when reading the file you have a success and error handler, check the error handler for a message